# How to convert gzip stream into a readable content and pipe it out in the request?

Tags: node.js, pipe, reverse-proxy

I am trying to make a proxy call to a website (somesite.com) and get the html from it. somesite.com is chucked and it is zgipped so I was unable to parse buffer (responseFromServer in my code) to be html (currently i get bunch of zumbbled string when i do res.write).
i tried `res.end` and `res.send` but neither of them work.

```
 function renderProxyRequest(req, res) {
        // somesite.com is gzipped and also is chunked.
        var options = {
            protocol: 'http:',
            hostname: 'somesite.com',
            // passing in my current headers
            headers: req.headers,
            maxRedirects: 0,
            path: req.url,
            socketTimeout: 200000,
            connectTimeout: 1800,
            method: 'GET'
        }
        var proxyrequest = someProxyApi.request(options);
        proxyrequest.on('response', function (postresponse) {
            // postresponse is a buffer
            //postresponse.pipe(res);
            var responseFromServer = ''
            postresponse.on('data', function (data) {
                    responseFromServer += data;
            });
            postresponse.on('end', function () {
                // getting some jumbled string onto the browser.
                res.write(responseFromServer);
                res.end();
            })

        });
        req.pipe(proxyrequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `postresponse` is a stream, you can probably do something like this:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
...
postresponse.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(res);
```

You have to check if the response is gzipped to begin with, by checking the `Content-Encoding` header from the remote server.

Alternatively, if you pass the original headers from the remote server to the client you're proxying the request for, you should be able to just pass the response data along as-is (because the original headers will tell the client that the data was gzipped). This obviously depends on the client being able to handle compressed responses (browsers will).

Comment: does .pipe(res); send it back to the client request?

Comment: @ravi yes, it does.